# set specific name and location while saving xml file in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have generated xml file through c# and want to save at specific location :

Eg: My Documents//

here's my code:

```
protected void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
StringWriter stringwriter = new StringWriter();
            XmlTextWriter xmlwriter = new XmlTextWriter(stringwriter);
            xmlwriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
            xmlwriter.WriteStartDocument();
            xmlwriter.WriteStartElement("root");
            xmlwriter.WriteStartElement("information");
            xmlwriter.WriteEndElement();
            xmlwriter.WriteEndDocument();
            XmlDocument docSave = new XmlDocument();
            docSave.LoadXml(stringwriter.ToString());
            //string dir = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
            docSave.Save(Server.MapPath("~/xml/") + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".xml");
}
```

What to write in server>Map Path

I tried

```
docSave.Save(System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDoc‌​uments),"xml")+ Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".xml");
```

But the file is not being saved into the xml directory.
Any solution?

Comment: what is the outputpath? (from `Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(En...`)

Comment: That I want to set ("My documents/xml").

Comment: No i don't want to know what you want it to be, i want to know what it actually returns.

Comment: (string filename) eg. xmldoc.Save(@"d:\xml\markers.xml");

Comment: Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(En...) 
this creates "xml<guid>.xml" file doesn't put file in documents/xml

Comment: What do you mean by it didn't help? Are you getting any error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to save inside Documents:

```
    StringWriter stringwriter = new StringWriter();
    XmlTextWriter xmlwriter = new XmlTextWriter(stringwriter);
    xmlwriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    xmlwriter.WriteStartDocument();
    xmlwriter.WriteStartElement("root");
    xmlwriter.WriteStartElement("information");
    xmlwriter.WriteEndElement();
    xmlwriter.WriteEndDocument();
    XmlDocument docSave = new XmlDocument();
    docSave.LoadXml(stringwriter.ToString());
    docSave.Save(System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDoc‌​uments), "xml") + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".xml");
```

If you want to save inside Documents/xml

```
    StringWriter stringwriter = new StringWriter();
    XmlTextWriter xmlwriter = new XmlTextWriter(stringwriter);
    xmlwriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    xmlwriter.WriteStartDocument();
    xmlwriter.WriteStartElement("root");
    xmlwriter.WriteStartElement("information");
    xmlwriter.WriteEndElement();
    xmlwriter.WriteEndDocument();
    XmlDocument docSave = new XmlDocument();
    docSave.LoadXml(stringwriter.ToString());
    System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDoc‌​uments), "xml//"));
    file.Directory.Create();
    docSave.Save(System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDoc‌​uments), "xml//") + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".xml");
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked like charm!

Answer (score 0):

You missed "\" after xml directory:

```
docSave.Save(System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(
Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDoc‌​uments),
"xml[here you miss: \\]")+  Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".xml");
```

You will find all your xml files in the Documents directory, all the files should looks like: xml[GUID].xml

You should write your code in a simplest way so you can find such issues easily.
You could write the code as following:

```
string outputDirectory =   Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDoc‌​uments), "xml");
string filename = string.Format("{0}.{1}", Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "xml");
string fullFileName = Path.Combine(outputDirectory, filename);
docSave.Save(fullFileName);
```